# Flask: Is it possible to return a set as a JSON response

Tags: python, json, flask, flask-restful

Whilst using Flask can one return a set as a json response from a rest endpoint?

For example:

```
@app.route('/test')
def test():

    list = [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4]

    unique_list = set(list)

    return json.dumps(unique_list)
```

I've tried this and get the following error:

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

I've also tried turning the set back into a list and returning that instead. However I am faced with the same error as above.

Any ideas?

Comment: @erip they would see that anyway. A list is mutable and unhashable. Calling your list `list` does not change its type.

Comment: 'list' variable name was just as an example for the post fyi not in actual source code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use flask's `jsonify` to return a JSON response. Also, don't use `list` as a variable name and convert the unique `set` back to `list`.

```
from flask import jsonify

@app.route('/test')
def test():

    my_list = [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4]

    unique_list = list(set(my_list))

    return jsonify(results=unique_list)
```

Comment: mylist should be casted to a tuple when using set.

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses all. Solution above worked. @dm295 why would using flasks' jsonify be better than json.dumps()?

Comment: @kmz `It turns the JSON output into a Response object with the application/json mimetype.`: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/api/#flask.json.jsonify